# Spawn a set of threads iteratively in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a function that populates entries in a large matrix. As the computations are independent, I was thinking about exploiting `std::thread` so that chunks of the matrix can be processed by separate threads.

Instead of dividing the matrix in to `n` chunks where `n` is the limit on the maximum number of threads allowed to run simultaneously, I would like to make finer chunks, so that I could spawn a new thread when an existing thread is finished. (As the compute time will be widely different for different entries, and equally dividing the matrix will not be very efficient here. Hence the latter idea.)

What are the concepts in std::thread I should look into for doing this? (I came across `async` and  `condition_variables` although I don't clearly see how they can be exploited for such kinds of spawning). Some example pseudo code would greatly help!

Comment: `I could spawn a new thread when an existing thread is finished.` Why? What's the point of letting one thread die only to immediately create another, when the existing one can do more work just as well? Create a queue of work items, have a pool of worker threads pick items from that queue and process them.

Comment: That makes total sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why tax the OS scheduler with thread creation & destruction? (Assume these operations are expensive.) Instead, make your threads work more instead.

**EDIT:** If you do no want to split the work in equal chunks, then the best solution really is a thread pool. FYI, there is a [thread_pool library in the works for C++14](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/executors/).

What is below assumed that you could split the work in equal chunks, so is not exactly applicable to your question. **END OF EDIT.**

```
struct matrix
{
    int nrows, ncols;
    // assuming row-based processing; adjust for column-based processing
    void fill_rows(int first, int last);
};

int num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); 
std::vector< std::thread > threads(num_threads);

matrix m; // must be initialized...
// here - every thread will process as many rows as needed
int nrows_per_thread = m.nrows / num_threads;
for(int i = 0; i != num_threads; ++i)
{
    // thread i will process these rows:
    int first = i * nrows_per_thread;
    int last = first + nrows_per_thread;
    // last thread gets remaining rows
    last += (i == num_threads - 1) ? m.nrows % nrows_per_thread : 0;
    threads[i] = std::move(std::thread([&m,first,last]{
                 m.fill_rows(first,last); }))
}

for(int i = 0; i != num_threads; ++i)
{
    threads[i].join();
}
```

If this is an operation you do very frequently, then use a worker pool as @Igor Tandetnik suggests in the comments. For one-offs, it's not worth the trouble.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the OP didn't want (Splitting the matrix into equal sized chunks)?